# Can not resolve method getSupportFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am getting error-

> "Can not resolve method getSupportFragmentManager()"

in below code.

For `getSupportFragmentManager()` we need to extend AppCompatActivity. But it gives errors in `addTab()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnMenuItemClickListener, OnMenuItemLongClickListener {

private static final String TAG_1 = "tab1";
private static final String TAG_2 = "tab2";
private static final String TAG_3 = "tab3";
private static final String TAG_4 = "tab4";
private static final String TAG_5 = "tab5";

TabHost mTabHost;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private ContextMenuDialogFragment mMenuDialogFragment;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    initMenuFragment();

    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    //mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(null);
    TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_1);
    tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
    tab1.setIndicator(createTabIndicator("Home", createTabDrawable(R.drawable.home)));
    tab1.setContent(new Intent(this, Home.class));
    mTabHost.addTab(tab1);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_2);
    tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
    tab2.setIndicator(createTabIndicator("Schedule", createTabDrawable(R.drawable.schedule)));
    tab2.setContent(new Intent(this, Schedule.class));
    mTabHost.addTab(tab2);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_3);
    tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
    tab3.setIndicator(createTabIndicator("My Schedule", createTabDrawable(R.drawable.star)));
    tab3.setContent(new Intent(this, MySchedule.class));
    mTabHost.addTab(tab3);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab4 = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_4);
    tab4.setIndicator("Tab4");
    tab4.setIndicator(createTabIndicator("Surveys", createTabDrawable(R.drawable.surveys)));
    tab4.setContent(new Intent(this, Surveys.class));
    mTabHost.addTab(tab4);

    TabHost.TabSpec tab5 = mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_5);
    tab5.setIndicator("Tab5");
    tab5.setIndicator(createTabIndicator("Menu", createTabDrawable(R.drawable.menu)));
    tab5.setContent(new Intent(this, MyMenu.class));
    mTabHost.addTab(tab5);
    getTabWidget().getChildAt(4).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mMenuDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "ContextMenuDialogFragment");
                }
            });



}

private Drawable createTabDrawable(int resId) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    StateListDrawable states = new StateListDrawable();

    final Options options = new Options();
    options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888;

    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    Bitmap unselected = TabBitmap.createUnselectedBitmap(res, icon);
    Bitmap selected = TabBitmap.createSelectedBitmap(res, icon);

    icon.recycle();

    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_selected}, new BitmapDrawable(res, selected));
    states.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, new BitmapDrawable(res, unselected));

    return states;
}

private View createTabIndicator(String label, Drawable drawable) {
    View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.text_view_tab_title);
    txtTitle.setText(label);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) txtTitle.getLayoutParams();
    txtTitle.setLayoutParams(params);
    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.image_view_tab_icon);
    imgIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    return tabIndicator;
}

//context-menu

private void initMenuFragment() {
    MenuParams menuParams = new MenuParams();
    menuParams.setActionBarSize((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.tool_bar_height));
    menuParams.setMenuObjects(getMenuObjects());
    menuParams.setClosableOutside(true);
    mMenuDialogFragment = ContextMenuDialogFragment.newInstance(menuParams);
    mMenuDialogFragment.setItemClickListener(this);
    mMenuDialogFragment.setItemLongClickListener(this);
}

private List<MenuObject> getMenuObjects() {

    List<MenuObject> menuObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    MenuObject close = new MenuObject();
    close.setResource(R.drawable.icn_close);

    MenuObject send = new MenuObject("Send message");
    send.setResource(R.drawable.icn_1);

    MenuObject like = new MenuObject("Like profile");
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icn_2);
    like.setBitmap(b);

    MenuObject addFr = new MenuObject("Add to friends");
    BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icn_3));
    addFr.setDrawable(bd);

    MenuObject addFav = new MenuObject("Add to favorites");
    addFav.setResource(R.drawable.icn_4);

    MenuObject block = new MenuObject("Block user");
    block.setResource(R.drawable.icn_5);

    menuObjects.add(close);
    menuObjects.add(send);
    menuObjects.add(like);
    menuObjects.add(addFr);
    menuObjects.add(addFav);
    menuObjects.add(block);
    return menuObjects;
}

@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.context_menu:
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ContextMenuDialogFragment.TAG) == null) {
                mMenuDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, ContextMenuDialogFragment.TAG);
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mMenuDialogFragment != null && mMenuDialogFragment.isAdded()) {
        mMenuDialogFragment.dismiss();
    } else{
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMenuItemClick(View clickedView, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onMenuItemLongClick(View clickedView, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Long clicked on position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Can you please help me why its showing this error?

And which class do I extend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getSupportFragmentManager` is method of `FragmentActivity`,not `TabActivity`,so you just replace it with `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: Thanks FireSun. Changing fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();   to   fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); gives error as Incompatible types Required android.support.app.v4.app.FragmentActivity   Found android.app.FragmentManager

Comment: you should import `android.app.FragmentManager`,not `android.support.app.v4.app.FragmentManager`

Comment: I appreciate it FireSun. mMenuDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "ContextMenuDialogFragment"); method uses android.support.app.v4.app.FragmentManager as a argument. Passing android.app.FragmentManager in show() method gives can not resolve method.

Comment: `ContextMenuDialogFragment` is your custom class? If so,you can change its method to receive `android.app.FragmentManager` parameter.

Comment: show() method is implemented in android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.java file. I can't change in ContextMenuDialogFragment as it's part of library which I am using for custom popup menu.

Comment: Is it possible to write the code that needs android.support.app.v4.FragmentManager in separate class file and when we need to use method show() we create the object of that separate java class and call the method?

Comment: I should say your design maybe wrong,you must know the lowest android version your app supports,then choose android.app.* or android.support.v4.*,and `TabActivity` has deprecated long ago,so I suggest you don't use it anymore,it will make your design simpler.

Comment: Thanks FireSun. Which class do I extend in my code as I tried extending Fragment,FragmentActivity,AppCompatActivity classes rather than TabActivity and getting error for one or other method in code. Can you please suggest the class which I extend in my code?

Comment: You'd better extends `AppCompatActivity`,this will make some methods like `addTab` compiles failed,because these method belongs to `TabActivity`,to fix these,you can custom your bottom tabbar and set a fragment for one tab by yourself,accroding your  ui design,maybe you can use `TabLayout` and `FragmentManager` to make it.there is a video you can refer:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQekzaAgIlQ

Comment: I am feeling lucky! Thanks a lot FireSun. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Fragment Activity like this:

```
  FragmentActivity mFragmentActivity;
```

And then you use this:

```
  mFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Thank you Johnny Cheuk.Changing above gives error on this line mMenuDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "ContextMenuDialogFragment"); as can not resolve method show(android.support.app.v4.app.FragmentActivity,java.lang.String);